# How can i use Service class inside BroadcastReceiver class

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I want to start Service class through BroadcastReceiver class 
I am getting toast “Phone is running” on running this application but I am not getting the second toast i.e  “in service”
The coding that I have done is…

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Intent i=new Intent(context,Myserve.class);
            context.startService(i);
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Phone is Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
}
}

class Myserve extends Service{


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you declared `Service` in manifest? and you need to make your `Service` as public class. Write it in separate file...

Comment: Must be sure that you have registered your Service in manifest file.

Comment: Did u get any error message in log???

Comment: yes i have registered

Comment: and am getting errors in logcat also

Comment: What error you are getting? Post logcat.

Comment: 03-08 12:38:11.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
03-08 12:38:11.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 12:38:11.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-08 12:38:11.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
03-08 12:38:11.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)

Comment: 03-08 12:38:11.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 12:38:11.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11452): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
03-08 12:38:11.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-08 12:38:11.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
03-08 12:38:11.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1947)

Comment: Make your **Myserve** service class as a separate class.

Comment: 03-08 12:38:11.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):  ... 10 more
03-08 12:38:14.187: I/Process(11452): Sending signal. PID: 11452 SIG: 9
03-08 12:39:07.057: D/dalvikvm(11599): newInstance failed: Lcom/callup/Myserve; not accessible to Landroid/app/ActivityThread;
03-08 12:39:07.057: D/AndroidRuntime(11599): Shutting down VM
03-08 12:39:07.057: W/dalvikvm(11599): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac8578)

Comment: ok i try doing this also

Comment: @AbhishekSuri Write `MyService` class in a separate file and that class should be `public`...

Comment: @AbhishekSuri You'r wel come...!

Comment: thanks that query is solved... could you please look over this query of mine...http://stackoverflow.com/q/22307033/3388066   @PiyushGupta